# How to represent averages and other aggregates in OOP?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have a Model called `Product`. `Product` has among other things a price, a category and a created date.

I want to show a table showing the average price and average age by category in many places. Sometimes I want just one category, sometimes everything, sometimes only products that have been in stock for more than a certain time etc.

At the moment I'm using Laravel's Query Builder to generate those numbers in my controller, then passing that to a view.

To help try to reuse it, I have this in the methods before I need it:

```
$product_averages_base_query = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('categories', 'products.MakeDescription', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('count(products.id) as TotalNumber'),
        DB::raw('AVG(Datediff("'.date('Y-m-d').'",products.created)) as AvgDaysInStock'),
        DB::raw('AVG(Price) as AvgPrice')
    );
```

Then when for the specific use case I use:

```
$averages = $product_averages_base_query->where('categories.name', '=', 'Example 1')->get();
```

or whatever the variant is.

This feels really "wrong" because I of course end up copying this code all over the place.

How do I represent this data in a way that will let me reuse it more easily? Should I have a class? What should it be called, and what's in it?

Should I have a Model somehow?

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As for the appropriate place, you could very easily use query scopes and drop everything in your model.  You'd probably want to start with your base query...

```
public function scopeBaseQuery($query)
{
    return $query->leftJoin('categories', 'products.MakeDescription', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('count(products.id) as TotalNumber'),
            DB::raw('AVG(Datediff("'.date('Y-m-d').'",products.created)) as AvgDaysInStock'),
            DB::raw('AVG(Price) as AvgPrice')
        );
}
```

And then continue with the category name scope...

```
public function scopeOfName($query, $name)
{
    return $query->where('categories.name', $name);
}
```

Add additional scopes as you need.

Then to use this, it would be quite easy...

```
$averages = Product::baseQuery()->ofName('Example 1')->get();
```

Comment: Does this make sense though, as it's not a property of Product, it's a property of all Products?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create an Eloquent class for the model and then put the functionality into a scope.

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeAveragesByCategoryName($q, $catName) {
        return $q->leftJoin('categories', 'products.MakeDescription', '=', 'categories.id')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(products.id) as TotalNumber'),
                          DB::raw('AVG(Datediff("'.date('Y-m-d').'",products.created)) as AvgDaysInStock'),
                          DB::raw('AVG(Price) as AvgPrice'))
                 ->where('categories.name', '=', $catName);
    }

}

$products = Product::averagesByCategoryName('Example 1')->get();
var_dump($products);
```

Or you could just as easily put the whole thing into a function.